# Update CSS Rule in style sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's consider there is a style sheet in an html page as shown below

```
#main {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
}

#content {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

now I have a situation where I have to update the CSS rule of `#main` meaning I have to add some css attributes like color, background etc.

So the Style sheet in my html page should be updated like shown below:

```
#main {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff;
}   

#content {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

I can use jQuery css to add CSS rules as shown below

```
$('#main').css('background','blue');

//but this is not adding #main in <style></style>
//output of above jquery code is: 
//<div id='main' style="background: blue"></div>
```

What I need is for it to add css attributes to a rule in the style sheet (i.e., #main in `<style></style>`)

I am developing a code editor which is why I face such a problem.

Comment: I believe what you're asking for might be tricky. However you can probably add a new style tag at the end of the `head` tag with the set of new rules?

Comment: What is the difference between adding to inline and inline style block? I you add with javascript it will be more maintainable to add inline than a separate style tag. Best would of course be if you create all your classes in a separate css file(or even SASS/LESS) and add/remove classes and ids where you want to change your style.

Comment: @Magnus you are right. best way is to creating all classes in css and add\remove classes using JavaScript.

Comment: modifying stylesheets in code is definitely possible, but jQueery is (thankfully) not the answer - use this google search https://www.google.com.au/search?q=modify%20stylesheet%20in%20javascript and rejoice

Comment: @MagnusKarlsson yes I can do so. But lot of wast code is generating. I already said I am developing a code editor so user may get messed up will all the code.

Answer (score 2):

it took me a long time but finally here we go: **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGxzOb)**

if we click on the `#main` element the `style` tag will get changed using the function that we just defined, so if we get the text of the `script` tag before the function it will be:

```
<style>#main {
      display: block;
      width: 500px;
      height:200px;
      background-color:#000;
  }

  #content {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
</style>
```

and then after the function is called it will be:

```
<style>#main {
      display: block;
      width: 500px;
      height:200px;
      background-color:#000;
      color:#FFF;
  }

  #content {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
</style>
```

**The Function:**

```
//*styleElem* is the target style tag
//*elemToChange* is the target element that we want to change inside the style tag
//*cssRule* is the new CSS rule that we want to add to the target element

function addCSSToStyleTag(styleElem,elemToChange,cssRule){
  var oldStyle=styleElem.text(),
      theElement=elemToChange,
      position=oldStyle.indexOf(theElement),
      cssToBeAdded=cssRule,
      closingBracketIndex=oldStyle.indexOf('}',position)-1,
      newStyle=oldStyle.substr(0,closingBracketIndex)+cssToBeAdded+oldStyle.substr(closingBracketIndex,oldStyle.length);
  styleElem.text(newStyle);
};
$('#main').one('click',function(){
  addCSSToStyleTag($('style'),'#main','color:#FFF;');
});
```

Comment: This is not totally functional, if we have an element with id #main_1 before #main in the text, the css will be added to it which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot explicitly catch css rules inside the current style, but as a work around you can append another style to the head with the new rules, it will override the existing rules as follows :

```
var newCss = "<style>#main{
                         display:block;
                         width:500px;
                         color: #333;
                         background:#fff;
                          }   
                        #content{
                        border:1px solid #ccc;
                       }  </style>";

$("head").append(newCss);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  var style="#main{display: block;
  width: 500px;
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;"};
  $('style').append(style);
```

This is assumed that you have only one `<style>` tag in page

Answer (score 0):

You can apply hardcore css to perticular div...Like this

```
    $('#main').css("background":"blue");
```